# Bigtable Client initialization stuck in Kubernetes container

Tags: go, kubernetes, grpc, alpine-linux, google-cloud-bigtable

We are trying to run a Golang app on Kubernetes which talks to Bigtable. The application seems to be stuck at creating the client:

```
bigtableClient := bigtable.NewClient()
```

upon setting the log level to info using:

```
export GRPC_GO_LOG_SEVERITY_LEVEL="INFO"
```

the error message is like this:

```
WARNING: 2019/06/05 08:14:13 grpc: addrConn.createTransport failed to connect to {dns:///bigtable.googleapis.com:443 0  1}. Err :connection error: desc = "transport: Error while dialing dial tcp: address dns:///bigtable.googleapis.com:443: too many colons in address". Reconnecting...
WA
```

We tried using the Alpine docker image but doesn't seem to work.
Has anybody faced this before?

Comment: {dns:///bigtable.googleapis.com:443 0  1} shouldn't it be {dns://bigtable.googleapis.com:443 0  1}

Comment: I am not configuring the dns. The google bigtable client internally makes the gRPC connection

Comment: have you installed CA certificates on your alpine pod ?

Comment: It's a curious error but there is no parameterless `NewClient` function in the library. You need to provide `context.Context`, the `project` and `instance` as well as optional `opts`. See https://godoc.org/cloud.google.com/go/bigtable#NewClient. I assume you're correctly passing Application Default Credentials too and are mounting these as a secret in order that the credentials are accessible to your container(s).

Answer (score 2):

Upon debugging, the issue was with one of the dependencies used while building the container. Using Go modules https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules to manage package versions solved the problem.